# attach a debugger or esc to cancel in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

When I want to start AVD in Android Studio, this message is displayed for me. where is the problem from?

[image: 1]

AVD starts successfully but this message is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem but my emulator is working fine. Use Android 9.0 and Pixel 3 API 28. The dialog box "attach a debugger or esc to cancel" occurs but the emulator works, you need to cancel this dialog box.

--->> use android 9.0 and pixel 3 api 28 emulator